# Help Object By Gerund Or Help Object To Infinitive

Tags: exam-questions

How has the law helped human workers?

If I answer this question, which of the following is suitable?

> 1.The law has helped human worker by limiting the numbers of working hours.
>
> 2.The law has helped human workers limit the numbers of working hours.

I prefer No.2# as I think " help object infinitive"  is suitable.

Answer (score 2):

Which is suitable depends on what you mean: your two sentences put forward quite different propositions.

> 1.The law has helped human workers by limiting the numbers of working hours.

In this sentence *the law* is the subject of *limiting*—it the law which limits working hours, and that 'helps' workers in the sense that it confers a benefit on them.

> 2.The law has helped human workers limit the numbers of working hours.

In this sentence *human workers* is the subject of *limit*—it is the workers who limit their own hours, with some unspecified 'help' (assistance) by the law.

Comment: Can I use "help the worker in limiting" to have the law as the subject.

Comment: @learner No; that construction is ambiguous: *in* may designate an action by either. If you moved the PP to the front, it would unambiguously designate the law as the limiter: "In limiting working hours the law helps workers."